# Unity Restharp Working on Editor but when I build to Android it gives Null Reference Exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, restsharp

I am developing a game with using RestSharp API.

Here is My extendable method for Send Function:

```
public async Task<T> Send<T>(string service, object obj)
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    string uniqueID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
    string buildID = Application.version.ToString();
    string platform = "1";
    #endif
    #if UNITY_IOS
    string uniqueID = UIDevice.identifierForVendor;
    string platform = "0";
    string buildID = PlayerSettings.iOS.buildNumber.ToString();
    #endif
    client.Timeout = -1;
    client = new RestClient(baseUrl + service);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Platform", platform);
    request.AddHeader("Version", "1");
    request.AddHeader("BuildID", buildID);
    request.AddHeader("BundleID", "1");
    request.AddHeader("DeviceID", uniqueID);
    request.AddHeader("AccessToken", "1");        
    request.AddJsonBody(obj);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    if (response.Content != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var jsonSerializerSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore };
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content, jsonSerializerSetting);            
        Debug.Log(result);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Example use of this code :

```
async Task<WelcomeRequest> Welcome()
{
    WelcomeRequest welcome = new WelcomeRequest
    {
        Language = language,
        Location = localization
    };
    var client = NetworkManager.Instance;
    var w = await client.Send<WelcomePayload>(Services.welcome,welcome);
}
```

Here is the method I use in the Start Method:

```
public async void WelcomeRequest()
{
    await Welcome();
}
```

When I Debug (var w) part everything is fine. Values ​​are coming through the API without any problems. I don't have any problems with server communication.

However, when I run the apk file that I have built using the Bluestacks emulator on an android device or windows, I cannot communicate with the API.

The log file content I get when I debug the application on the android device is as follows:

```
01-19 12:58:30.023: I/Unity(2155): MemoryManager: Using 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator.
01-19 12:58:30.102: I/Unity(2155): SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 8, Memory = 3537mb
01-19 12:58:30.102: I/Unity(2155): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf0), 4 little (mask: 0xf)
01-19 12:58:30.102: I/Unity(2155): ApplicationInfo com.MinityGames.Play2Win version 1.0 build 1c9a8217-614e-4241-b6bc-7bb29cf326ca
01-19 12:58:30.102: I/Unity(2155): Built from '2020.3/staging' branch, Version '2020.3.24f1 (79c78de19888)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a', Stripping 'Enabled'
01-19 12:58:30.234: I/Unity(2155): Company Name: MinityGames
01-19 12:58:30.234: I/Unity(2155): Product Name: Play2Win
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.MakeRunDelegateCtor (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.GetRunDelegateCtor (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.MakeDelegate (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate].Compile (System.Boolean preferInterpretation) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at RestSharp.Reflection.ReflectionUtils.GetGetMethodByExpression (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at RestSharp.PocoJsonSerializerStrategy.GetterValueFactory (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.269: E/Unity(2155):   at RestSharp.Reflection.ReflectionUtils+ThreadSafeDic
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.MakeRunDelegateCtor (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.GetRunDelegateCtor (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda.MakeDelegate (System.Type delegateType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate].Compile (System.Boolean preferInterpretation) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at RestSharp.Reflection.ReflectionUtils.GetGetMethodByExpression (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at RestSharp.PocoJsonSerializerStrategy.GetterValueFactory (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
01-19 12:58:33.317: E/Unity(2155):   at RestSharp.Reflection.ReflectionUtils+ThreadSafeDic
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): LanguageClass[]
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): <Send>d__11`1:MoveNext()
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): System.Action:Invoke()
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback:Invoke(Object)
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): UnityEngine.WorkRequest:Invoke()
01-19 12:58:33.446: I/Unity(2155): UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:Exec()
```

The part that says "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." API communication is started to be provided.

In Editor there is no exception everything works as fine as possible.
Am I miss something?

Comment: General question why do you `client.Timeout = -1;` **before** `client = new RestClient(baseUrl + service);` ?

Comment: And what is `NetworkManager.Instance`? Are you sure it exists in a build?

Comment: NetworkManager is the script with my extendable method. In the continuation of the lines, I used it for abbreviation as a client in order not to write long each time. all fields in my scenes tests and sprites are completely empty before the game starts. All values ​​come from the server. The values ​​on the editor come without any problems and the game is played without any problems. However, when I get the build and control it from the server side, I cannot communicate with the api.